# When declaring an enum, should you force the type to byte for under 256 entities?

Tags: c#, enums, types

If you have an enum in your application and you only have a few items, should you force the underlying type to be the smallest possible type?

```
    enum smaller : byte
    {
        one,
        two,
        three
    };
```

Comment: To be clear, I was talking about best practices rather than optimization, though this question came across as an optimization question.

My point was really since you can specifiy it, should you "always" specify or should you or let the compiler decide?

Comment: You can see examples of this in the framework eg Shutdown enum https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,6f25689a8b08d287

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No.  Don't prematurely optimize **unless** you've proved with a profiler that it's actually a problem.

Comment: I think .NET is optimised for Enums to be ints anyway.

Comment: To be clear, I was talking about best practices rather than optimization, though this question came across as an optimization question.

My point was really since you can specifiy it, should you "always" specify or should you or let the compiler decide?

I guess leave as is works for both.

Comment: how would you prove with a profiler whether byte or int is more efficient?

Comment: @Brian, many different ways. The one that comes to mind is memory stats. If you notice a particular object is created in enough bulk that it's size is noticeable on a profiler then you can start looking at ways of shaving down the size of the structure.  This would be one possibility.

Comment: I don't think you'd notice with enums for typical use, but I guess that's your point :)

Comment: @Brian exactly :).  I'm not saying this optimization is not without it's uses. We have done this type of optimization before on our code base (usually C++ bitflags). But we had a lot of profile data to back this up when we did it.

Comment: If you prove with a profiler that something is the problem, it wouldn't be premature optimization.

Comment: If you want to shave to 5 bits off per enum, I'd say switch to another language/framework. I'd be more worried about strong references than that

Comment: @Chris S Where did 5 bits come from? An `int` is 32 bits, a `byte` is 8 bits.

Comment: @0b101010 he has 3 values in his enum, so he only wants to use 3 bits not 8 (so saving 5 bits)

Comment: @ChrisS I didn't interpret the question as asking that. The OP was asking about changing from the default `int` to a smaller `byte`. The C# specification explicitly states that an enum's underlying type must be a `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong`. I think you might be misunderstanding how enums work.

Comment: I come to this from a different viewpoint. I write lots of networking and serial protocols in which it is important to have variables of the proper type. I use UInt32 UInt16 and the like instead of uint, ushort, etc. for convenience and to prevent errors. In my case I usually force the enum type to match the protocol definition so that I can serialize it directly.

Comment: it is required to match the second parameter passed  to `Enum.IsDefined` with type of enum. otherwise the method throws exception. since I was parsing a file I changed enum type into `short` instead of casting parameter to `int`

Comment: @JaredPar what about memory consumption? what if I store this type in a cache

Answer (score 39):

**Relating to best practice:**

When you don't have a particular reason for making the enum a type byte, you should leave it as the default.

Any time you use an enum in a switch statement you should have a "default" clause for an invalid enum value.  So it doesn't matter if you are checking for 256-NumRealEnumValues or 2^32-NumRealEnumValues.  Both will have a default clause that handles all invalid cases.

One reason for explicitly setting the type of the enum, is if you want your enum to correspond to another type in your program and you need to explicitly cast between them.

Changing the type to the smallest fit will not help you with versioning problems either.  Unless you have exactly the max size of the enum filled out.  By versioning problems I mean when you have a compiled dll using the enum, then you add a new enum value, some code may execute that was not meant to go in the "default" clause of a switch statement.

**Relating to efficiency:**

No there is no benefit in terms of efficiency to make it a byte.

int is more efficient to use because the cpu on x86 has 32-bit registers.  Copying into a register is done 32-bits at a time.

When you use a smaller type, you have to zero out part of the register and copy into the rest of the register's lower order bits.

Comment: You are thinking of only CPU performance. Whilst the cost to zero out the required register bits is pretty much negligible, the efficiency gains in memory usage can be substantial.

Comment: "can be substantial" is technically true, but I doubt it will turn out to be substantial very often.  In my experience, single bytes (not in arrays) are most often padded out to a word boundary, so many bytes take up just as much memory as an int.

Comment: how about when I use enums in structs? Do I need to slim them down to byte to make the whole struct smaller?

Comment: What about array of enum-s? It is strange idea but theoretically an array of byte enum-s will use 4x less memory than int-s.

Comment: Definitely needs to be a byte, for example, if it's an Entity Framework entity property that you want to be a byte, and keeping it small is particularly important if it's part of a clustering key.

Answer (score 8):

The only reason to do this is if you are storing or transmitting this value using a defined protocol that demands the field to be of that size.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the only reason.  I often do this because I need to keep a hundred million or more items in memory, and the three bytes per record savings is quite significant.

Comment: @Jim: If you have so many items in memory, it is more likely that you have a problem somewhere else. You are sacrificing performance for space. You should either swap those items from memory, or get more memory.

Comment: @Juliano I don't think it is indicative of a problem elsewhere. In the world of real-time algorithmic trading you often need to keep millions of data items (e.g. transactions, order book updates) in memory at a time. Shaving off 3 bytes per data item yields a significant benefit.

Answer (score 3):

If you are mapping the model with enum to another model, or serializing it, or your enum is reflected to the database column – then I would suggest you to specify the type explicitly.

---

Scenario:
You have a column in database: `status_id` with type `tinyint`. And you have enum in your code: `enum Status { Well = 1, Bad = 2 }`. And you use this enum in some entity. Let's say you use entity frameworks core 2.0. If you try to read/write this entity from database you will get the error "Unable to cast object", unless you specify the `byte` type explicitly.

Comment: This appears to be the only valid reason to do this. If you are simply mapping to a data model of type tinyint, this seems fine. You're still likely casting to a byte value...

Answer (score 2):

What would be gained? You'd save a whopping 3 bytes of memory, at the cost of slightly slower execution and less intuitive or readable code. (Reading this, I have to wonder whether pyou actually had a reason for making it a byte, and what that reason might have been. Presumably you went out of your way to use a non-default type for a reason).

If you plan to store millions of these things then yes, saving a few bytes on each may pay off. Otherwise, no.

It's the same reason you don't typically use byte or short instead of int.

Comment: I'm using an enum to clean up magic numbers that are supposed to be bytes (adding to a list of bytes). In this case it is useful. Any other case it'd be micro-optimising indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign a certain integer type to enumerations and let C# fall back to the default `int`<sup>1</sup> <strike>but let the .NET environment figure out the best "size" for the enum</strike>. As JaredPar said, *if* you change the data type, you *should definitely* check whether it actually helps.

The thing is that 32-bit integers are "natural" on x86 processors because they can be easily align in an optimal fashion.

<sup>1</sup> [By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: .NET does not "figure out the best "size" for the enum".  [By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net core, if you call Enum.IsDefined to check if the passing in value existed in an enum, you should ensure types are the same.

> ArgumentException: Enum underlying type and the object must be same type or object must be a String.