# When writing on disk, should I use the smallest type possible?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

In my application I have to write some data structures on a binary file, and a lot of them contains enums. Should I convert the enums to the smallest type possible (`qint8`) or should I stick with 32 bits (`qint32`)?

Will it have a positive or negative impact? I'm most concerned about speed and not space.

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Event &event)
{
    out << (qint8)event.myEnum;
    //Also write other fields...
}
```

I've seen some posts advicing against this kind of optimization ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648823/when-declaring-an-enum-should-you-force-the-type-to-byte-for-under-256-entities) and [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144792/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-smaller-data-types-for-variables-to-save-memory)), but they are about memory and not disk writing.

**Edit:** To clarify: when using `QDataStream` I can't write or read an `enum` directly, I have to convert it to a integer type. I'm assuming 8 bits is enough because in my context there will always be less then 127 values (and I'm also using -1).

Comment: Why do you assume, that `qint8` would be sufficiently large? Seriously, let the compiler decide on the underlying type. It knows what it does.

Comment: Usually disk are block devices (512 bytes, for example). This means that you first cache your data before writing it on disk (which is done by SO, by the way). In this way, there are a lot of things to be said about it. So, I'll just provide one argument: you manage this file indirectly via memory, which means that any advice concerning memory is valid. Of course, if you need to do a lot of writing, things can change. The best answer is profile it.

Comment: *"8 bits is enough because [...] there will always be less then 127 values"* - Hm... `enum E { E_e = 256; };` Also, sign extension can lead to corrupted data on input.

Comment: @IInspectable - how is 256 less than 127?

Comment: @ddriver: 256 is certainly not less than 127. However, 1 is, which is the number if values in my example.

Comment: @IInspectable I still don't get your point. The OP clearly states the values are between -1 and 127.

Comment: @ddriver: That's not what the OP says. Their statement is: There are at most 127 (distinct) enumerated values, and one of the values explicitly assigned is -1. There are, in particular, no restrictions on the range of assigned values.

Comment: @IInspectable - to me the "less then" implies the OPs English is not pristine. This, in combination with the particular values of 127 and -1 implies that what he means is that the enum values will always be less than the value 127, and not that the number of values in the enum will be less than 127 and possibly going above 127 in value. Also, the OP evidently has an idea of the range of values a signed byte can hold, thus further reinforcing my interpretation.

Comment: @ddriver: I explained, why a byte may not suffice to store the data, given the restrictions the OP outlined (without an additional indirection anyway). If you believe that what the OP said and what the OP meant are not the same, you should ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to use the smallest types since you cut down on the streamed data rate and it'll take less time and energy (think mobile!) to write it out. If your code produces the data slower than the disk can consume it, the wall time won't change if you use larger types, but the energy use will still be higher the larger data types you choose.

Overall, I'd worry more about whether your serialization is future proof - make sure you version your file at an appropriate level (e.g. either one version for the whole file, or a version for each subsection, or even version each structure - depending on how the code is structured and what makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a byte, then use a byte. `QDataStream` can certainly work on byte resolution. There aren't any disadvantages to this, and if you serialize of lot of those objects, you will see tangible benefits.