# How much memory use byte enumerations and does this optimize memory/speed in C #?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, enums

Is using byte enums in C# for small enumerations a benefit or a good practice?

Does this reduce memory usage?

Does that improve speed?

Example:

```
enum Fruits : byte { Apple, Orange, Banana }
```

What is the advantage over this:

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Orange, Banana }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: [When declaring an enum, should you force the type to byte for under 256 entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648823/8967612)

Comment: sorry guys but these are all non-questions here in the comments. Designed to make you feel better by making @riera feel "less than". OP is obviously new, why not encourage them with help rather than come off as gods from atop.

Comment: @OlivierRogier maybe you can reopen the question, since obviously it is NOT opinion based. You just provided a definitive answer, I don't see a single opinion.

Comment: @Riera I would like to apologize for my colleagues behavior. It is quite rampant in this industry. Don't let it stop you...

Comment: @OlivierRogier You wrote the answer that I need. I can't understand why you closed the question.

Comment: I voted to reopen so that @OlivierRogier can post his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Investigating with the Visual Studio Machine Code Window**

For `byte enum` and `int enum` we can see that the memory is aligned to `4 bytes` in each case on a Windows x64, even using the `Flags` attribute. But `long enum` consume `8 bytes` per value.

*It is therefore unnecessary to use byte enum because it consumes the same memory and the speed is the same and using byte alignment should be only useful on 8-bit machines.*

**Explanation**

It is because .NET use 32-bit registers for integers on x32 as well as on x64 Intel/AMD even with AnyCPU or x64 target.

The .NET compiler doesn't optimize for memory but for speed, because of the processor internal bus size that is optimized (16/)32-bit on x32 CPU or (32/)64 bits on x64 CPU. So 32-bit access is the best speed on x32 and 64-bit is the best on x64. Any other size "force" the processor to down/up size. I wrote (16/) and (32/) because these access are optimized to be less slow than others down/up sizing.

This is because the .NET compiler favors speed over memory, especially since it is a virtual machine, and therefore slower than native code. And it favors 32-bit for compatibility reasons. Indeed, 32-bit registers and memory access are more optimized on x32/x64 machines, and a lower alignment is a loss of performance (unless we have an 8 or 16-bit processor). Only memory pointers are 32 on x32, and 64 on x64 if compiled AnyCPU or targetting x64.

So any data shorter than 32-bits should be aligned to 32-bits nowaday, and it could be 64 in the future.

Thus enums shorter than integers as well as integral values less or equal than 4 bytes size in structs and classes are 4 bytes aligned, so we lost 3 bytes per byte on a .NET Machine under x32 or x64, unless we modify the [struct packing size](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack) (default is 4 bytes).

*Remark*

A [marshal sizeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof) on a struct or a class instance gives the "used (unmanaged) data size" but not the real reserved memory including lost blocks to store the data.

**Example**

```
enum FruitsByte : byte { Apple, Orange, Banana }
enum FruitsInt { Apple, Orange, Banana }
enum FruitsLong : long { Apple, Orange, Banana }
```

*For byte*

```
var fb1 = FruitsByte.Apple;
mov dword ptr [rbp+0A4h],ecx  

var fb2 = FruitsByte.Orange;
mov dword ptr [rbp+0A0h],1  

0xA4 - 0xA0 = 4 bytes
```

*For int*

```
var fi1 = FruitsInt.Apple;
mov dword ptr [rbp+9Ch],ecx  

var fi2 = FruitsInt.Orange;
mov dword ptr [rbp+98h],1  

0x9C - 0x98 = 4 bytes
```

*For long*

```
var fl1 = FruitsLong.Apple;
mov qword ptr [rbp+90h],rcx  

var fl2 = FruitsLong.Orange;
mov qword ptr [rbp+88h],rcx  

0x90 - 0x88 = 8 bytes
```

**Full machine code**

```
      var fb1 = FruitsByte.Apple;
00007FF7E93C0B19  xor         ecx,ecx  
00007FF7E93C0B1B  mov         dword ptr [rbp+0A4h],ecx  
      var fb2 = FruitsByte.Orange;
00007FF7E93C0B21  mov         dword ptr [rbp+0A0h],1  

      var fi1 = FruitsInt.Apple;
00007FF7E93C0B2B  mov         dword ptr [rbp+9Ch],ecx  
      var fi2 = FruitsInt.Orange;
00007FF7E93C0B31  mov         dword ptr [rbp+98h],1  

      var fl1 = FruitsLong.Apple;
00007FF7E93C0B3B  movsxd      rcx,ecx  
00007FF7E93C0B3E  mov         qword ptr [rbp+90h],rcx  
      var fl2 = FruitsLong.Orange;
00007FF7E93C0B45  mov         ecx,1  
00007FF7E93C0B4A  movsxd      rcx,ecx  
00007FF7E93C0B4D  mov         qword ptr [rbp+88h],rcx
```

**More information**

[Data structure alignment (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

[x64 Architecture - CPU registers (MSDoc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture)

[8086 to i486 Instructions Set](https://www.ordisoftware.com/files/intel/Intel-Instructions-8086-to-i486.pdf)

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html)

Comment: Compare sizes `2` vs. `8` [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/maRHEn) for structs of two byte-sized vs. int-sized enum types.

Comment: Byte addressing is equally efficient regardless of alignment. And `SizeOf` gives the actual memory footprint - add for example an int at the end of each of the previous structs, and the sizes will change to `8` vs. `12` (*not* `6` vs. `12`, because of the int alignment). This is all described in the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8). So using enums wider than needed wastes memory in structs, and it is not always true that "*it consumes the same memory*".

Comment: "*It is therefore unnecessary to use byte enum because it consumes the same memory*" The problem with this part of the answer is that it's written as a general truth, which it is not.

Comment: @divx Thanks for helping me to improve the answer with more details, but it seems that you have missed the point of the question and the technology of the microprocessors which I approached as well as the marshalling.